# BlackBerry 10 Cascades: How do I load data into a DropDown?

Tags: qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I have managed to load data from a remote Json web service into a QML ListView, but there doesn't seem to be any such thing for the DropDown control.

Does someone have an example or an alternative method to accomplish a DropDown bound to attachedObjects data sources in Cascades?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have an alternate method for you, Do note that I have used google's web service here for demonstration purpose, you need to replace it with your url & parse response according to that.

```
import bb.cascades 1.0

Page {
    attachedObjects: [
        ComponentDefinition {
            id: optionControlDefinition
            Option {
            }
        }
    ]
    function getData() {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState == 4) {
                var response = request.responseText
                response = JSON.parse(response)
                var addressComponents = response.results[0].address_components
                for (var i = 0; i < addressComponents.length; i ++) {
                    var option = optionControlDefinition.createObject();
                    option.text = addressComponents[i].long_name
                    dropDown.add(option)
                }
            }
        }

        // I have used goole's web service url, you can replace with your url
        request.open("GET", "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + "Ahmedabad" + "&sensor=false", true)
        request.send()
    }
    Container {
        DropDown {
            id: dropDown
        }
        Button {
            onClicked: getData()
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Its working, returning the right amount of values, but trying to access fields in my json objects is returning undefined. not sure how to debug it. Im pretty lost in this development to be honest.

Comment: I used a DataSource but the important part was the ComponentDefinition. Thanks!

Comment: Hi,how can get the values from this dropDown and pass to my  web service url.?